# Angular ng-pattern - 1 ou 2 números

Tags: html5, angularjs

No código abaixo preciso fazer com que o ng-pattern receba 1 ou dois números, sendo que, o formata seja em mínutos, ou seja, nó mínimo 0 ou 00 e no máximo 59.

`<input type="text" step="any" value="" ng-model="job.ValorIntervalo" min="0" max="60" ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$/">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para essa sua validação basta apenas colocar a expressão regular abaixo:

```
^([0-5]{1}\d{1})$|^(\d{1})$
```

Você pode realizar os testes [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/4XS91l/3)

Comment: Felipe, excelente!! Funcionou perfeitamente, um abraço!

Comment: Se a resposta foi  útil não esqueça de marcar como respondida, para que isso venha ajudar outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema. Abraço